# Syntax error when using google module maps

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am writing code and I need a specific time zone and I use the google maps library, I copied the code from the github, but it still gives an error. I am use Python 3.7

I use this library for the first time.

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=('Here my API')
# Geocoding an address

geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')


# Request directions via public transit
now = datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions("Sydney Town Hall",
                                     "Parramatta, NSW",
                                     mode="transit",
                                     departure_time=now)
```

Error:
  line 7
   geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain 
  View, CA') SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you download the git file or import it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't close `( )` line above:

Look there:

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=('Here my API')
```

It should look be closed up:

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=('Here my API'))
```

Everytime on syntax, there isn't reason of lib

Comment: XD Thanks a lot!